# Is the time for light to go a certain distance the same amount of time sped up through relativity?

Tags: speed-of-light, time, relativity

If you were to stand on the tower of my Lemmon and had an atomic clock that was exactly synchronized with one at tucson, (6734 feet difference) for 24 hours, it was shown to be roughly a 20 nano second difference because of the laws of relativity. Could the time for light to go that distance (4734 feet) be the same as the time difference caused by relativity?

So, if you were looking down, you will be seeing the past, but is it because of the time that is sped up due to relativity or it it because of the time it takes for light from Tucson to arrive at your eyes (kind of like how you can see the past of the universe if you look fat enough) or both?

Answer (score 0):

> **Could the time for light to go that distance (4734 feet) be the same as the time difference caused by [<strike>relativity</strike> [*gravitational time dilation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation)]?**

No, for two reasons.

- The [units are not the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis), one is nanoseconds per day. The other is nanoseconds.
- light travels 4734 feet in about 4813 nanoseconds not 20.